# how to retrieve the saved photos on the server as byte[] using retrofit2 on android and then display them with Picasso

Tags: android, asp.net, retrofit2, picasso

I've developed a website under MVC ASP.NET using c#. It is to let the users save their data including photos which are then saved as `byte[]` on the respective database that is SQL server. I've thus designed a web api to retrieve the data as `JSON` from the database. Plus I've developed a mobile application using which the web API retrieves and displays the data. I used `retrofit2` to use web API in android. The mobile application displays all the data correctly except for the photos. My question is: how can I retrieve the saved photos on the server as `byte[]` using `retrofit2` on android and then display them with Picasso?

Answer (score 0):

Define your model:

```
public class SomeApiResponse {
    private byte[] image;
    // setter and getter...
}
```

Now define your service API:

```
public interface RestAPI {
    public Call<SomeApiResponse> callService();
    // ...
}
```

Convert byte[] to Bitmap:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
```

And finally load bitmap into ImageView:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

And yes, you do not need Picasso to do this!